# Django TestCase error in parent class setUp

Tags: python, django

I am a unit-test newbie executing the following tests in Django 1.4 using TestCase and mock:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from mock import patch

class BaseRegistrationTestCases(TestCase):
    def setUp(self, backend):
        # use these common fields for building mock form data
        self.form_fields = (
            'form_email',
            'form_companyname',
            'form_companytype',
            'form_region',
            'form_socialgoals',
        )

        self.route = '/auth/registration/{backend}/'.format(backend=backend)

    @patch('authentication.views.RegistrationView._get_user_by_backend')
    @patch('authentication.views.RegistrationView._set_base_context')
    def test_invalid_form(self, mock_legacy_uid, mock_base_context, invalid_form_data):
        """ Should include invalid fields in context and serve error message """
        mock_legacy_uid.return_value = 12348
        mock_base_context.return_value = {}
        self.response = self.client.post(self.route, invalid_form_data)

class FacebookRegistrationTestCases(BaseRegistrationTestCases):
    def setUp(self):
        super(FacebookRegistrationTestCases, self).setUp('facebook')

    def test_invalid_form(self):
        invalid_form_data = {form_field: "" for form_field in self.form_fields}
        super(FacebookRegistrationTestCases, self).test_invalid_form(invalid_form_data=invalid_form_data)

        for field in self.form_fields:
            invalid_key = field + '_invalid'
            self.assertEqual(self.response.context[invalid_key], 1)
```

The tests fail with the following error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_invalid_form (authentication.tests.BaseRegistrationTestCases)
Should include invalid fields in context and serve error message
----------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: setUp() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setUp() method in `BaseRegistrationTestCases` requires two arguments to be passed. This is why you have the error, only 'self' is being passed.

However, you cannot pass the additional argument `backend` directly like this into setUp()! As you see it extends TestCases, so you would have to overwrite the class `__init__` to get this to work correctly with that extra argument.